# PostgreSQL 12 crash trying to add PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

When I try to execute `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`

I get this error :

```
geoall=#CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
```

these are the logs for PostgreSQL

```
2020-04-15 12:53:23.732 EDT [177498] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
2020-04-15 12:53:23.733 EDT [177498] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2020-04-15 12:53:23.734 EDT [177787] db@geoall WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-04-15 12:53:23.734 EDT [177787] db@geoall DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, becauther server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2020-04-15 12:53:23.734 EDT [177787] db@geoall HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2020-04-15 12:53:23.734 EDT [177786] db@geoall WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-04-15 12:53:23.734 EDT [177786] db@geoall DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, becauther server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2020-04-15 12:53:23.734 EDT [177786] db@geoall HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2020-04-15 12:53:23.737 EDT [177783] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-04-15 12:53:23.737 EDT [177783] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because anotherr process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2020-04-15 12:53:23.737 EDT [177783] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2020-04-15 12:53:23.758 EDT [177498] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2020-04-15 12:53:23.777 EDT [179200] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-04-15 12:52:56 EDT
2020-04-15 12:53:23.777 EDT [179201] postgres@geoall FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2020-04-15 12:53:23.823 EDT [179200] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2020-04-15 12:53:23.828 EDT [179200] LOG:  redo starts at 2/996F5960
2020-04-15 12:53:23.885 EDT [179200] LOG:  redo done at 2/99945FC0
2020-04-15 12:53:23.914 EDT [177498] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

and I can't install PostGIS.

Version of Linux:

```
Linux  5.4.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.4.19-1 (2020-02-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Is the server fine otherwise? Enough space, RAM etc?

Comment: I don't know I have 512 Mb of ram and the other queries run them without problems

Comment: Please post an Answer instead of altering the Question to contain the solution. The former is a recommended outcome, and the latter is a way to have the question closed as *non-reproducible*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me i just have to view top memory hungry process whith this command

`ps -eopid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head`

stop (kill -STOP pid process) or kill process, and retry to add, and it shuld work.